# Creating a command Line Python Editor

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is possible to create a .py program which is capable of running Python Commands, creating new variables, much like the IDLE provided. If not what can i use to create such a programs. Essentially im creating a new language as an extension to Python. Example:

```
>> 1+1
>> 2
>> print "yo"
>> yo
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you asking how to write a program that can run Python, how to extend Python, or how to write your own programming language?

Comment: Why is the standard python command line interface insufficient?

Comment: um write a program that can run python.

Comment: @Bill Eventually i will create a new language that will be based off Python. I just want to know how to create the CMD like interface for now.

Answer (score 3):

Batteries included, see the [code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) standard module (not much sense in repeating the docs in here, ask if anything's unclear). Also, both bpython and IPython are examples on how the Python core can be augmented with alternate interfaces.